# How can I write a custom evaluation metric for mmyolo instance segmentation?

Tags: python-3.x, yolov5, mmyolo, instance-segmentation

I am currently working on a custom dataset in the format of `CocoDataset`. I want to evaluate the dataset on `mean_iou` but the `CocoMetrics` only seem to provide `mAP` metrics.
I tried to use `mmEval` metrics but I get an error as described below.

My config is based on this [example config](https://mmyolo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/15_minutes_instance_segmentation.html). Training and evaluation works on the default val and test evaluators.

```
# ... dataset paths, dataloader etc...

# import the mmeval metric class
from mmeval import MeanIoU

# specify the mmeval metric for the test evaluation
test_cfg = dict(
    test_evaluator=dict(
        type='MMEvalMetric',
        metric=MeanIoU(num_classes=num_class)
    )
)
# ... other configs
```

This gives me the error

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    MeanIoU=<class 'mmeval.metrics.mean_iou.MeanIoU'>
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

....
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
SyntaxError: Failed to format the config file, please check the syntax of: 
MeanIoU=<class 'mmeval.metrics.mean_iou.MeanIoU'>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Or a better way to evaluate with `mean_iou`?